# How to exclude test directories from coverage with meson?

Tags: code-coverage, meson-build

I would like to know if there is a way to specify that we want to exclude all the directories `*/tests/*` from the paths explored for coverage in `meson.build` ?

Performing coverage analysis over the test files themselves is quite confusing because they are mostly covered at 100% and if you have a lot of them it mask the real cover rate from your real code. So, I really would like to avoid counting the test files themselves.

I already know about [this issue on github](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/3287) (I posted there myself quite long time ago) but I would like to know if people started to develop workarounds about that.